# CSRF token mismatch in Laravel and Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am using `Axios` to Post my data from `Vue` to `Laravel Controller`.

I have used this below code to resolve the problem. But it's not working!

```
import Axios from 'axios'
window.axios = require('axios');
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
};
```

This is my Method which I want to Post:

```
onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.$http.post('store', {
     email: this.email
  }).then( (res) => {
     console.log(res.data.newsletter_success)
  }).catch( (err) => {
     console.log(err);
  })
}
```

What is the problem?? There is a `CSRF` setup in Laravel `bootstrap.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Well it may be caused by the first 2 lines in your code:

```
import Axios from 'axios'
window.axios = require('axios');
```

You should choose one way of importing axios and go with that

Have a look at this solution:

```
window.axios = require('axios');
Vue.prototype.$http = window.axios

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
};
```

Now we know for sure that Vue.prototype.$http (which is window.axios) will also send the CSRF headers you set.

Answer (score -1):

You can give `headers` like `ajaxSetup`

```
this.$http.post('store', { email: this.email}, 
{ 
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
   } 
}
```